# How to compare a list with the result from an iteration?

Tags: python, android, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code block:

```
Game_names = ['Game1', 'Game2', 'Game3', 'Game4', 'Game5']
for i in driver.find_elements_by_id("com.project.ProjectName:id/itemContainer"):
    for title in i.find_elements_by_id("com.project.ProjectName:id/title"):
        print('Game titles are: ' + title.text)
         if Game_names == title.text:
             print('Games titles are correct')
         else:
            print('Games titles are not correct')
```

I need to check if the game names are correct.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the expected output? please add it to your post.

Comment: do you want check whether `title.text` is in the list `Game_names`

Comment: Hi,
~output:
Game titles are:
Game1
Game2
...
Game titles are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that two iterables are equal, use `all()`:

```py
a = [0,1,2]
b = (0,1,2)
all(x == y for x, y in zip(a,b))
```

In your case you will have to extract the text:

```py
titles = i.find_elements_by_id("com.project.ProjectName:id/title")
all(x==y.text for x,y in zip(gameTitles, titles))
```

Unless the titles really are all in each element, which case presumably you want to split them:

```py
titles = i.find_elements_by_id("com.project.ProjectName:id/title")
for title in titles:
    assert all(x==y.strip() for x,y in zip(gameTitles, title.text.split())
```

Note that if order could change, you need to sort first, either by sorting in-place or by iterating `sorted(thing)`

### Checking *one* element

If you only want to check whether an element is in the list, just do:

```py
for title in titles:
    if title.text.strip() in GameTitles:
        ...
```

Comment: Managed to use somehow: `for title in titles:
    if title.text.strip() in GameTitles:`
The other ones are returning different errors: no text attribute, assert error..
I will use this one
Thank you!